# SQL Server: delete data in all tables -> is there a better performing query?

Tags: sql-server

I am searching for a better way to delete all table contents. Currently our procedure looks like the below one. Unfortunately it seems to have different issues like forced serialization, function joins.... the query is performed after every test in parallel on 4 different databases and consumes much time. Is there a better (faster and with better performance) way? Even optimizations for the current query would be fine.

```html
   IF (OBJECT_ID('delete_tables') IS NOT NULL)
 DROP PROCEDURE delete_tables
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE delete_tables AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(255);
 DECLARE @tablenames TABLE (table_name VARCHAR(255));
 DECLARE @tablenamestmp TABLE (table_name VARCHAR(255));
 DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(MAX);
 
 INSERT INTO @tablenames 
        SELECT st.name 
        FROM sys.tables st
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON st.schema_id = ss.schema_id
  INNER JOIN sys.partitions sp ON sp.object_id = st.object_id
  WHERE st.is_ms_shipped = 0 
          AND ss.name = 'dbo' 
          AND sp.index_id IN (1,0)
    AND st.name NOT LIKE 'comm_specialtable_%'
  GROUP BY st.name 
        HAVING SUM(sp.rows) > 0

 INSERT INTO @tablenamestmp 
        SELECT * FROM @tablenames;

 WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @tablenamestmp)
 BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 1 @table_name = table_name 
        FROM @tablenamestmp;

  IF @table_name IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN

   SET @text = 'ALTER TABLE '+ @table_name+ ' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
   EXEC sp_executesql @text;

  END
  DELETE FROM @tablenamestmp WHERE table_name = @table_name;
 END

 INSERT INTO @tablenamestmp SELECT * FROM @tablenames;

 WHILE exists(SELECT 1 FROM @tablenamestmp)
 BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 1 @table_name = table_name FROM @tablenamestmp;
  IF @table_name IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN

   SET @text = 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; DELETE FROM '+ @table_name
   EXEC sp_executesql @text;

   SET @text = 'ALTER TABLE '+ @table_name+ ' WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all'
   EXEC sp_executesql @text;

  END
  DELETE FROM @tablenamestmp WHERE table_name = @table_name;
 END


end
```

Comment: as per my understanding you need to delete data from all the tables in database

Comment: Do `TRUNCATE` instead of  `DELETE` it will be faster, after all you are deleting all the data by not using any condition. and are you sure your `SP` is working ?

Comment: Be careful about using truncate as will reset your seed as well.

Comment: That is ok for tests, but it means you need to remvoe relationships first ;) Bigger problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use TRUNCATE TABLE instead of DELETE FROM as mentioned in the comments to avoid logging - however why are you doing this in the first place? Use of an in-memory database if you are using EF, Database snapshots if you are on a recent version of SQL or delete the database and publish a new blank one, or have a backup of initial state and restore that over the top instead would all probably be a better approach.

Comment: Truncate Table does not work with foreign key constraints (disabling them would be time intense too). That is why we use delete in the first place. We are using the database for a java application that is using hibernate in the background. If I try to use a new database or a snapshot I would have to reset the connection pool or restart the whole application which is time consuming too.